# How to set permission to (.env) in windows 10 server xampp localhost

Tags: laravel, database, permissions, xampp, localhost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkkvz.png)

i`m using xampp server on localhost and when try to install the database for laravel script get this error on file permission i`m trying to change the permission to full control but still error appear how can i solve it ?!

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permissions to the file by using chmod command.

Here, 755 is an octal expression of the permission “rwxr-xr-x”. Now, breaking down the chmod 755 value,

7: 4 + 2 + 1: Read, write, and execute (user owner).

5: 4 + 0 + 1: Read and execute permissions (group owner).

5: 4 + 0 + 1: Read and execute permissions (others).

```
chmod 775 /<file name>
```

In your case try to give storage path  if it's not working means add permissions for .env

Comment: how can i add permission for .env ?